# Does Kähler structure on X imply Kähler structure on the loop space of X?

Tags: loop-spaces, loop-groups

Does Kähler structure on $X$ imply Kähler structure on the loop space ($LX$) of $X$? Since the loop space of $X$ is the space of maps from the circle $S^1$ to $X$, I suspect one may use the pullback via the evaluation map $e:LX\rightarrow X$ of the closed Kähler form $\omega$ on $X$ to obtain a closed two-form $e^*\omega$ on $LX$. Am I correct?

Comment: For what it is worth, five years later: you seem to be trying to arrive at the transgression map that sends differential $p$-forms on $X$ to $(p-1)$-forms on $LX$, so the Kaehler form on $X$ would go to a 1-form on $LX$, rather than a 2-form.

You might be interested in the following string theory reference on Kahler structure on $LX$ and papers referencing that: https://inspirehep.net/literature/235315

Answer (score 1):

See Part I of [Sergeev's book...](http://ir.nul.nagoya-u.ac.jp/jspui/bitstream/2237/12240/1/geoquant.pdf) (he talks more about Lie groups) - see also [Henrich Falk's diplomarbeit (2009, Berlin)](https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-tuberlin/files/2237/henrich_falk.pdf) page 26

Comment: Could you kindly point out the section I should be looking for, I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @MeerAshwinkumar An even more explict description is in the second reference...

Comment: Igor, your references do not really resolve the question which OP is asking. The issue of integrability of the almost complex structure is a delicate one: For the loop space of a 3-dimensional Riemannian manifold (the case I thought about) the answer is that the almost complex structure is formally integrable but, in general, not integrable, see [Lempert's paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/246726852_Loop_spaces_as_complex_manifolds). What happens when the target is Kahler I am not sure.